# Calculating lat/lons from PostGIS table which has projected coordinate system?

Tags: qgis, postgis, coordinate-system

I have a PostGIS table in a projected coordinate system (EPSG: 28355 or MGA94 Zone 55). In QGIS (with the PostGIS manager plugin) I calculate a coordinate by performing the following SQL:

```
UPDATE gisprod.buildings SET easting = x(centroid(the_geom))
```

Now I want to add a "lat" and "lon" field to this table and calculate the values using the appropriate coordinate system, in this case that would be (EPSG:4283 or GDA94).

Is there a way I can specify in the SQL statement to calculate the x/y coord using a different coordinate system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this, it should work:

```
ALTER TABLE gisprod.buildings ADD COLUMN lat double precision;
ALTER TABLE gisprod.buildings ADD COLUMN lon double precision;

UPDATE gisprod.buildings SET lon = ST_X(ST_Transform(centroid(the_geom),4283));
UPDATE gisprod.buildings SET lat = ST_Y(ST_Transform(centroid(the_geom),4283));
```

Answer (score 6):

I think [ST_Transform](http://postgis.org/documentation/manual-1.5/ST_Transform.html) is your friend.