# Problem when calculating longitude and latitude for points

Tags: postgis, postgresql, latitude-longitude, srid

I have a PostGIS database with SRID=900913 (Google Mercator) and I would like to know the latitude and longitude of points.

I use this command:

```
ST_X(ST_TRANSFORM(the_geom,4283))
```

Following what is written [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11917/how-do-you-calculate-lat-lons-from-a-postgis-table-which-has-a-projected-coordin), but it doesn't work. I get the error:

```
ERROR: AddToPROJ4SRSCache: Cannot find SRID (4283) in spatial_ref_sys
SQL state: XX000.
```

I tried to add 4283 in the spatial_ref_sys:

```
INSERT into spatial_ref_sys (srid, auth_name, auth_srid, proj4text, srtext) values ( 94283, 'epsg', 4283, '+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs ', 'GEOGCS["GDA94",DATUM["Geocentric_Datum_of_Australia_1994",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6283"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4283"]]');
```

But I still have the same error.

What does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ST_Transform function takes the output coordinate system as the second parameter - see [ST_Transform](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Transform.html). The input co-ordinates should already be stored in the GEOMETRY_COLUMNS table / view.

Also, you seem to have the SRID wrong, it is 4326 for standard WGS84 lat/lon.

Comment: If I change the SRID and use `SELECT ST_X(ST_Transform(the_geom,4326)) from table`, I have the same error message, `ERROR: AddToPROJ4SRSCache: Cannot find SRID (4326) in spatial_ref_sys`

Comment: What is the output of "select * from spatial_ref_sys where srid = 4326"?

Comment: No output, nothing.

Comment: And for `select * from spatial_ref_sys`: srid _94283_ and _96627_ (resp. auth_name _epsg_ and _sr-org_, resp. auth_srid _4283_ and _6627_)

Comment: I found the solution: first I used the [code from spatialreference.org in order to add SRID 4326] (http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/postgis/) and then I used `ST_X(ST_TRANSFORM(the_geom,94326))` to get my result.

Answer (score 3):

You need to populate your `spatial_ref_sys` table, e.g.:

```
psql -d your_db -f spatial_ref_sys.sql
```

This will give you SRID `4326`, but not `94283`, which [doesn't appear to be any publicly recognized SRID](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/?search=94283&srtext=Search).

To add `900913` (i.e. leetspeek for GOOGLE), see the PostGIS instructions at http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/SphericalMercator

Comment: Oh, I see you found `94283` from http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/23477/1872 .. oh buoy.

Comment: In order to populate my `spatial_ref_sys`, I don't understand why you suggest the first line of code (`psql...`). Why isn't it possible to simply use [the code from spatialreference.org](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/postgis/)?

Comment: I found the solution: first I used the [code from spatialreference.org in order to add SRID 4326] (http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/postgis/) and then I used `ST_X(ST_TRANSFORM(the_geom,94326))` to get my result.

Comment: You can use 94326 for an SRID, you will have less troubles with 4326, since that's what most people know. (I think 94326 is a bug on spatialreference.org ). I.e., to fix the problem, rename 94326 as 4326. I recommend using `spatial_ref_sys.sql` since it isn't broke like spatialreference.org